# How to set ACL permissions for SSH_AUTH_SOCK in a RemoteCommand?

Tags: bash, ssh, acl, ssh-agent, setfacl

I'm trying to forward my SSH agent and then grant permissions to the SSH_AUTH socket. The permissions are for another user on the remote host. My ssh config:

```
Host myhost
    Hostname 1.1.1.1
    ForwardAgent yes
    User foo
    IdentityFile "~/.ssh/foo"
    RequestTTY yes
    RemoteCommand setfacl -m bar:x "'$(dirname ${SSH_AUTH_SOCK})'"; setfacl -m bar:rwx "'$SSH_AUTH_SOCK'"; bash -l
```

The variable `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is expanded correctly on the remote host, however I get errors such as:

`setfacl: '/tmp/ssh-tsmWmrhbEu': No such file or directory`

It does work if I run it within a script on the remote host and specify its path in `RemoteCommand`.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Ensure SSH_AUTH_SOCK is set
if [ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ]; then
    echo "SSH_AUTH_SOCK is not set. Exiting."
    exit 1
fi

# Set permissions for the specified user
setfacl -m bar:x "$(dirname "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK")"
setfacl -m bar:rwx "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK"
```